# reading excel file in windows using perl

Tags: perl

How do I read an .xlsx file in windows7 using perl module use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.
it gives me an error that no excel data in file.Does windows require some other module to read data from an excel file. please help

**Edit:** I have now installed Spreadsheet::XLSX and am trying this program, but it still doesn't work:

```
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xlsx');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
  die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ){
  my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
  my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

  for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
    for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
      my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
      next unless $cell;
      print "Row,Col= ($row, $col)\n";
      print "Value=", $cell->value(),"\n";
      print "Unformatted=", $cell->unformatted();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `.xlsx` ≠ `.xls`! [Use the search, Luke](https://metacpan.org/search?q=XLSX).

Comment: which module to use then for .xlsx

Comment: Well, the first hit of the seach I linked to is [Spreadsheet::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet::XLSX). Never used it, but looks quite nice.

Comment: I tried Spreadsheet::XLSX ,but still not working

Comment: “It's not working” is a very useless description of any problem. Did the module install allright? What Perl distribution are you using (ActiveState/Strawberry)? If the module installed, what code are you using to access the file?

Comment: I am using strawberry . yes the modules have been installed properly, I would have known if that would not have been the case .

Comment: use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xlsx');
if ( !defined $workbook ) {
die $parser->error(), ".\n";}
for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ){
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
next unless $cell;
print "Row,Col= ($row, $col)\n";
print "Value=", $cell->value(),"\n";
print "Unformatted=", $cell->unformatted();
}}}

Comment: You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18811707/edit) to show your code, which allows better formatting

Comment: have you read the documentation of that module? You are still trying to access the file with Spreadsheet::ParseExcel!

Comment: NO I am not using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.that documentation was informational, thanks for it.I am using Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX.

Comment: Your above code contains `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new()`. This should be `Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new`, according to the docs.

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: They are two different modules, although `Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX` mimics the API of `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`.

Comment: @user2702225: so is the question answered now?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get at the data, regardless of formatting, I suggest you open the `.xlsx` with whatever office software you're using and export it to CSV format. On MS Excel and LibreOffice Calc at least, this can be accomplished via  `File`->`Save As` and selecting CSV as your file type.

You can either parse the resulting CSV with native Perl or use a module like [Parse::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Parse-CSV-2.00/lib/Parse/CSV.pm).